# Trying to addEventListener to looped array

Tags: arrays, events, listen

I'm pretty sure I've coded the event handler part wrong. When the array goes through and loops it does product a list on the page. I just need that list clickable with an event listener, then a series of re-direct based on if statements for comparison...ideas ?

```
window.onload = eventMonitor;



    function eventMonitor(){
    document.getElementById("names").addEventListener('click', reRoute, false);
    document.getElementById("hiddenText").addEventListener('mouseover', treasureRoute, false);


    function createName(){

        var streetNames = ["Carmen", "Napoli", "Oscar", "Haven", "Tampa"];
             //this top partscript creates a for loop that will take each array [item] and simply right it to the screen. 
                 for (i=0; i<streetNames.length; i++){

                var mName = "Martin";
                var node = document.createElement("li");
                var textNode = document.createTextNode(mName + " " + (streetNames[i])); 
                node.appendChild(textNode);
                document.getElementById("names").appendChild(node);
            }
        }
        function reRoute(){
                if(names === 'Martin Carmen'){
                    routeWindow = window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSC_Carmen");
                }
                else if(names === 'Martin Napoli'){
                    routeWindow = window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSC_Napoli")
                }
                else if(names === 'Martin Oscar'){
                    routeWindow = window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSC_Oscar")
                }
                else if(names === 'Martin Haven'){
                    routeWindow = window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MT_Haven")
                }
                else if(names === 'Martin Tampa'){
                    routeWindow = window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV_Tampa")
                }
        }
        function treasureRoute(){
                shipWindow = window.open("file:///Users/User/something.html");
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do does not require JavaScript. JavaScript, while useful in many circumstances, is error prone as you have noticed. The anchor tag is used to navigate between pages, which is why you inject `<li><a href="Url">Text</a></li>` elements into the DOM.

If you would nonetheless want to use JavaScript in a situation like yours, you would program your event handler to comply with the `addEventListener` API:

```
const names = document.getElementById('names');
names.addEventListnener('click', event => {
   const { target } = event;
   console.log(`${target.tagName} was clicked!`);
});
```

Comment: its an assignment for school, where they want event handlers attached to functions, i assume = event; where event === myFunction();

Comment: [Event handlers are functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) whose first argument is anything implementing the [Event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Event handlers are attached to objects implementing the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface. Clickable things such as most DOM nodes are such objects. For dispatching so-called synthetic events, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events.